A bound on inverses of invertible operator?

I am studying this proof, and I do not understand the last statement which claims the convergence. Particularly, I do not know how to make a bound on the inverse $\lVert \psi^{-1} \rVert$.
Here, $GL(E,F)$ is the set of linear isomorphism from $E$ to $F$, $L(E,F)$ is the space of bounded linear operators, and $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces.
Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

The last claim is just that the operator norm is submultiplicative, not unlike how it is true for matrix norms. Can you be more specific as to what you don't understand?

@PrincessEev Sorry for being unclear. What I do not understand is the statement "With this inequality, the limit is clearly zero." I don't know how to bound the norm of inverse of $\psi$ to show the limit is zero.

Taking inverse is continuous. As $\psi \to \varphi$, we have $|\psi^{-1}| \to |\varphi^{-1}|$, which is enough to prove the claim.

@DavidGao Thanks for your help. It means I need to show that the mapping $J$ in the proof is a continuous map. Is it right?

@hna That is correct, yes.

@DavidGao When I read this proof, I thought the author want to show the differentiability first, which then implies the continuity. Thus, I think there is another way to prove the claim. Anyway, thanks.

@hna You can sort of just combine the two proofs in one, which is what I’ve seen some authors do. But with the way this is written, without continuity as a prior lemma this cannot work.

@DavidGao I see. This is the second of the two lemmas used to prove the inverse function theorem in Banach spaces. The first is about the openness of the linear isomorphisms in the bounded linear maps. Probably, the proof is terse and leaves the continuity for the readers.

@hna The proof that the collection of invertible linear maps being open in all bounded linear maps usually will implicitly prove taking inverse is continuous as well. You can just look into that.

@DavidGao Yea. I have already known how to prove it. Thanks again.
